# After if statement still getting null objects displayed in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

actually i have an if statement which filer the null objects and is working, but when i try to insert something in join() like join("li") all null objects are displayed in page like in the image and i just want to display objects which are not null, so i just tried with another join("\n") and also is not working properly.
[image: output]

```
var vitalTest = document.getElementById("vitalComments").value
              = systemList[0].comments.join("");

//alert(vitalTest);

if (vitalTest == ""){
}else{
    document.getElementById("vitalComments").innerHTML = systemList[0].comments.join("<li>");
    var vitalTitleq = document.getElementById("vitalTitle").innerHTML
                    = systemList[0].systemName;
}
```

Comment: It would help if we could see what an example of `systemList[0]` looked like

Comment: vitalTest == "" doesn't mean null. use (typeof vitalTest === 'undefined') and or vitalTest === null

Comment: yes, actually this filter is working too, but still getting in li all null elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement only will be true if all elements of the array are empty. So in the cases where only some of the elements are not empty it is going to go to the else statement where you still use the empty values.

Instead just use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or polyfill to filter out empty values and use the new filtered array

```
valuelist = systemList[0].comments.filter(comment=>comment);
```

`comment=>comment` is just simply an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that will return the item and will be tested as truthy or falsy. And since null,undefined and empty strings test as falsy they will be filtered out. Note you will need a more adequate function if needing to keep values like 0 or other falsy type values.

Demo

```js
var list = [1,null,"text",null,44];

var filtered = list.filter(item=>item);

document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = "<li>"+filtered.join('</li><li>')+"</li>";
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: i used:
var list = systemList[0].comments;

                 var filtered = list.filter(item=>item);

                 document.querySelector("vitalComments").innerHTML = "<li>"+filtered.join('</li><li>')+"</li>"; but still not working

Comment: @EdwinBossman, In what way is it not working? Did you get an error in the console, is it showing the wrong things....?

Comment: the issue is for ul, because i deleted vitalComments and i call ul and is working, but i really need output in vitalComments

Comment: switch out `document.querySelector` for `document.getElementById`. I just used querySelector as for the example.

Comment: sorry i missed #vitalComments

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following function.

```
function commentList(objID, comments) {
  if(Array.isArray(comments) && comments.length>0) {
  var filteredComments = comments.map(function(x) {
      x = x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm,"");
      if(x.length>0) {
          return '<li>'+x+'</li>';
      }
  });
  document.getElementById(objID).innerHTML = filteredComments.join("");
  }
}
```

```js
function commentList(comments) {
  if(Array.isArray(comments) && comments.length>0) {
  var filteredComments = comments.map(function(x) {
      x = x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm,"");
      if(x.length>0) {
          return '<li>'+x+'</li>';
      }
  });
  document.getElementById("vitalComments").innerHTML = filteredComments.join("");
  }
}
var comments = ["comment1"," ","","comment2\n","comment3"];

commentList(comments);
```

```html
<ul id="vitalComments"></ul>
```